# How to hide control in repeater in asp.net throught java script

Tags: asp.net

How to hide control in repeater in asp.net throught java script

Comment: You will have to give a little bit more detail than this. Show us some code, which control you wish to hide, etc...

Comment: The largest stumbling block, is if you are not using .net 4.  You will want predictable IDs for your controls in the repeater.

Comment: "How to hide control in repeater in asp.net throught java script". Let me ask *you* a question first - "How to ask questions on Stack Overflow"? Answer: Read the FAQ's.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u want to hide your primary key. jusst put this in your repeater

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="whatever" runat="server" text="any value"/>
or
<... style="display:none;" />
```