# Javascript hide control in Repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to hide a table row in repeater control in ASP.NET?

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript? It appears you are asking about server side repeater controls. If there is a specific client side angle to this you may want to phrase your question more clearly.

Comment: **exact** duplicate of [How to hide control in repeater in asp.net throught java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497427/how-to-hide-control-in-repeater-in-asp-net-throught-java-script) please do not ask duplicate questions - the reason you haven't received proper answers is because your question is unclear and needs rewording/expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any element of document by [jquery .hide() method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)